# Include a generated coupon code in Order E-mail Template if the subtotal is above a specified amount

Tags: email-templates, coupon, coupon-codes, order-email

Can this be done in Magento automatically? For example I have a promo in my site that is something like this.

If the customer's total order is $100 or above, an uniquely generated coupon code will be included in the new order template that will be sent to the customer's e-mail.

I tried looking of how to set it up inside Magento admin, but it seems to be not a built-in feature. Any suggestions or quick+dirty ways to implement this are welcome.